# Unmet dependencies

Tags: vim, apt, python

I am trying to compile vim and install with "--enable-pythoninterp" flag, which needs the python-dev package.

INFO
I obtained the vim source from ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/unix/vim-7.3.tar.bz2
Vim7.3 is not available yet using apt.
Using Ubuntu 10.10

But, `sudo apt-get python-dev` results in broken packages error message ->

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.6.6-2ubuntu1) but 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 is to be   installed
E: Broken packages

How can I best resolve this issue?

---

```
$ apt-cache policy vim python python-dev
```

```
python:
  Installed: 2.6.6-2ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.6.6-2ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.6.6-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main i386 Packages
vim:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:7.2.330-1ubuntu4
  Version table:
     2:7.2.330-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main i386 Packages
python-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.6.6-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.6.6-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `$ apt-cache policy vim python python-dev`. That's what happens when you try to type half asleep.

Comment: Ok. Does what I suggest below work for you? As Frederik pointed out, in this case, it may be a simple matter of updating your sources. However, this is a common situation, so it is good to know how to resolve it generally.

Comment: @Faheem I have installed python2.7 & python2.7-dev for the meantime.

Comment: This should be easy to fix using the information in the answers. python 2.7 is not the default python, and if you try to use it you will create new and unnecessary complications.

Answer (score 1):

This is the usual message apt produces when you have have packages which are at different apt priority. See man apt_preferences. python 2.6.6-2ubuntu1 is not of sufficiently high priority to be installed, so apt is trying to install 2.6.6-2ubuntu2, which does not satisfy the dependency. More information is needed to resolve this. Please provide the output of

```
$ apt-cache policy vim python python-dev
```

Also post your /etc/apt/preferences and /etc/apt/sources.list files.
Also give details of how you obtained the vim source. Is this an upstream source? Did you download the source using apt-get source or similar? If I understood this correctly, you are trying to install a customized version of the vim package. Is that correct?

Based on your `apt-cache policy` output, you just need to downgrade python from `2.6.6-2ubuntu2` to `2.6.6-2ubuntu1`. As you can see, it does not currently correspond to any version in the archives. Do you know where you got it from? So do

```
$ apt-get install python=2.6.6-2ubuntu1
```

and then try your

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

again.

Comment: I have un-installed vim. So, `apt-cache vim policy python python-dev` is giving error. Post updated.

Comment: updated post with output for `apt-cache policy vim python python-dev`.

Comment: If i am downloading from the main server, how was python2.6.6-2ubuntu2 installed? How do I reset my apt??

Comment: I tried `sudo aptitude install python=2.6.6-2ubuntu1` but aptitude asks me to remove virtually everything. look at the output. http://pastie.org/1712658

Comment: @N 1.1: Don't try and downgrade to a specific version. It may be that 2.6.6-2ubuntu2 (for example) is now the current stable, so that would be the wrong thing to do. Also, try using apt-get not aptitude. First run `apt-get update`, then `apt-get install python/stable python-dev/stable`. This is basically what Frederik was suggesting above, but will force a downgrade to stable if necessary. Also, please update your output of `apt-cache policy vim python python-dev` above. Incidentally, using a username with no spaces would be preferable, I don't know if the notify system has problems with such.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your update got the packages in between uploads of packages: http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick-updates/python-dev both versions should be 2.6.6-2ubuntu2. I'd try:

```
apt-get update
```

and then retry

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python python-dev
```

If this does not work, I'd try switching to another ubuntu mirror to get the packages from there.

Comment: I think you meant `apt-get install` instead of `apt-cache`.

Comment: Why do you update with `aptitude` and then install with `apt-get`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not already, **try changing your package repository reference to 'Main' or the United States**. Doing this fixed my Python-dev unmet-dependencies problem (my 12.04 install *was* using the United Kingdom package repository, previously).

1. In 'Ubuntu Software Center' (USC) go to the menu/tab 'Edit => Software Sources'.
2. Change the 'Download from' drop-down value to 'Main Server' or a server in the United States.
3. Leave USC, the open 'Update Manager' from Ubuntu's program menu, and 'Check' for software update (or issue 'sudo apt-get update' in a terminal window).
4. Update your software as you normally would, e.g. via 'Update Manager' or apt-get/aptitude in a terminal.

This repaired my repository and I went on to install whatever I needed afterwards, as normal.

Before rectifying my problem with the above instructions, various aptitude/apt-get commands suggested that I remove many, many packages, but, as you can apreciate, I didn't fancy loosing my 6-months+ of package additions, and that's even though I snapshot the package list at times (see my [gist](https://gist.github.com/sixman9/3023d73a83a3ec407d83) for hints)! I'm really glad I found out about the instructions I'm leaving here.

Hope this helps.