# What information do I need to solve an APT dependency issue?

Tags: apt

I've seen several times people with unmet dependencies, which apt-get doesn't tells straightforward what's the problem, like this one:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.31) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 9.2.1-1ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libx11-6:i386 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxcb-dri2-0:i386 (>= 1.8) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxcb-glx0:i386 (>= 1.8) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxcb1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxdamage1:i386 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxfixes3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
```

I know that walking through all dependencies `apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386` until I hit something is available, but in this case it will be a painful job due the amount of packages. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Is there a real example, and what is the command line used here?

Comment: @FaheemMitha it is a real example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bunch of information that would help you:

1. Include the complete command that caused the issue in first place.
2. Include information about the packages involved with:

   ```
   apt-cache policy name-of-packages-involved
   ```

   So, in your case is the output of `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386` minimum.
3. The output of `sudo apt-get check` and possibly `sudo dpkg -C` also improved the chances you have.
4. The complete output of `sudo apt-get update` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}` can help in certain situations.
   In case you are trying to install a package, the output of aptitude's `why-not` command to easily figure out:

   ```
   aptitude why-not sysvinit-core
   i A systemd-sysv Breaks sysvinit-core
   ```

When asking for help about solving this issues, always **include the full output** of everything asked, this would expedite the solution of the problem.

Answer (score 12):

A reasonable first thing to try is to ask apt why it is doing what it is doing. This can be done with the `-o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes` option. E.g.

```
apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
```

If apt is not forthcoming, the standard approach to debugging such issues is to check the priority numbers of the available versions of each package mentioned in the error message. This is commonly done using `apt-cache policy`.

For example, to use just the first part of the error message, you should run

```
apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386
```

How one proceeds then depends on what this shows. It is often also useful to run just

```
apt-cache policy
```

which will show all the package sources available, along with their priority numbers. This information is usually specified in one or both of `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

People trying to get help here should first post the results of these commands **in their question**. That will likely be enough information to determine the problem.

Real-life examples of problems:

1. [Unmet dependencies after using a backports
   repository](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118585/4671): The user
   included sources for `www.deb-multimedia.org`, without pinning it to a lower
   priority. Never include third-party sources without pinning it to a
   lower priority. Note that this should not be necessary for
   well-behaved repositories which provide packages for the default
   release, but `www.deb-multimedia.org` is well known for not playing
   nice with Debian, and in general, you should not trust unknown sources.
   More generally, if you know a repository is not designed to be used with your
   system, pin it at a lower priority. E.g. testing/unstable sources on Debian
   stable.
2. [Unmet dependencies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9859/4671): The
   user somehow managed to install a version of python that wasn't the
   default version on his system. Naturally, all hell broke loose.
   Moral of the story, make sure you are only installing versions of
   packages that are correct for your system. As above `apt-cache policy pkgname` will tell you.
3. [dpkg / apt-get wants to install and overwrite different
   package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93021/4671): The user tried
   to install packages even though his underlying `dpkg` database was
   broken. Moral, if you see messages coming from `dpkg` that something
   or the other is wrong with your packages, in this case

   ```
   0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 2 not  
   fully installed or removed.
   ```

   your package database has problems. First fix them, before you try to install
   anything else. If `apt-get -f install` doesn't work, you may need to
   operate at the `dpkg` level to fix things.