# Dependency issues when installing MySQL

Tags: debian, software-installation

I've searched around this Stack Exchange network for this particular solution, it seems others have encountered something similar but not quite under the same lines as mine. I've been trying to install Apache, MySQL and PHP on my system.

Apache installed just fine as presented in my guide, however when trying to install MySQL I get the following dependency message:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
>   been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
>   resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  mysql-server :
>   Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed E:
>   Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I'm somewhat lost at this post, I am running the Debian distribution. It may also be better to let you know that I've tried installing this once before *(quite a long time ago)* and haven't tried since.

If you wish a link to the guide I mentioned, it's from [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-debian). Thank you

---

When trying to do `apt-get install mysql-server-5.5` I get the following:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  mysql-server-5.5 :
>   Depends: mysql-client-5.5 (>= 5.5.40-0+wheezy1) but it is not going to
>   be installed
>                       Depends: libdbi-perl but it is not installable
>                       Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (>= 5.5.40-0+wheezy1) but it is not going to be installed
>                       Recommends: libhtml-template-perl but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
>   packages.

---

Also when performing `apt-get update` the following shows up aswell:

> Release file for
>   http://debian.res.um.edu.mt/debian/dists/wheezy-updates/Release is
>   expired (invalid since 42d 23h 56min 2s). Updates for this repository
>   will not be applied.

Comment: What if you try to install `mysql-server-5.5`?

Comment: What release of debian? See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121180/

Comment: @fkraiem Gives me a weird message, I shall post it on the main question underneath in a minute. Faheem - Debian Wheezy(7), reading that post now thanks

Comment: Added another part which shows the error when trying to use `apt-get update`. Have also tried autoclean and autoremove. Nothing seems to fix the issue

Comment: The error for `apt-get update` is caused by the mirror having an out-of-date copy of wheezy-updates. Can you use any other debian mirrors instead of this one?

Comment: @wurtel - Sorry for the late reply. I triedd doing that however my desktop environment isnt loading anymore. Ill try doing it in command line.