# Package dependencies Debian

Tags: linux, package-management

I have a problem when installing certain software for Debian Jessie. I use `apt-get install`.

Sometimes it works, but in most cases I get the message:

> The following packages have unsolved dependencies ... dependent on  ... but ... should be installed. Problems can't be corrected. You have defect packages.

I get crazy. I have no clue how to tackle these problems. I don't need a quick fix for a certain installation but a general method or tutorial how to solve this package problem when it occurs.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121180/4671.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe.

Comment: Unresolved dependencies are often the result of mixing different repositories and releases. It might be useful to know the content of /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: @cryptix: Did you try to do: `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: @perror: only apt-get update

Comment: @cryptix: Okay.

Comment: Does `apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove --purge && apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove --purge` complete successfully, or where does it stop, and with which error?

Answer (score 1):

I find the interactive mode of `aptitude` helpful in these situations.

It's worth reading the manual, but in short:

1. Start `aptitude` with no arguments
2. Press `e` to enter the resolver
3. Look at the first solution it offers.  Probably there's an action you really don't want (e.g. uninstall your favourite game) - press `r` to mark that action rejected.  (It's a toggle, so you can undo accidental marks with the same keypress).
4. If there's a suggested action that you think really should happen, you can toggle forcing that with `a`.  Use this sparingly, as it can over-constrain the resolver quite easily.
5. Press `.` to see the next solution, which will take into account your rejections and accepts.  With luck, this will be acceptable to you; if not, then repeat from step 3.
6. Press `g` to preview and `g` again to perform the update.  Or, leave Aptitude, and the next `aptitude install` will apply the update (useful if you download packages automatically during off-peak times).