# unmet dependencies not going to be installed

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dependencies

I am trying `sudo apt install vulkan-utils` on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

 But I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
vulkan-utils : Depends: vulkan-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I read on this post [apt-get: reasons for “…but it is not going to be installed”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394031/apt-get-reasons-for-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed) that I should try `sudo apt install vulkan-tools` which I did successfully, `sudo apt install vulkan-utils`is still giving me the same error message though.

Comment: The most common cause of this is adding repositories that are incompatible with your OS. Apt is extremely fragile in that regard.

Comment: alright, so the repository I added for `vulkan-utils` may not be compatible with my OS?